# Getting number of characters in a unicode string in python

Tags: python, unicode

How can I get the number of codepoints in a string which may contain unicode characters 3 byte long. https://unicode-table.com/

For example for "I❤U" I would like to get 3.

Doing `len(str)` returns the number of bytes, so for the above example I would get 5.

Comment: Decode from the encoded bytestring to Unicode then, do you know the codec used?

Comment: Down voter please explain.

Comment: @MartijnPieters utf-8 I think

Comment: Then decode from UTF-8 and take the length of that. You'll get the number of *codepoints*, which may include combining marks and other grapheme clusters.

Comment: `len(bytestring.decode('utf8'))`. You may want to read up on [Python and Unicode](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html).

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks for the help and for the link. But why are claiming that my question is off-topic. Obviously if I was an expert in python/ decoding I would not ask this question, but I'm not.

Comment: It is *incomplete*. You are missing a reproducible case. Your input is dependent on the configuration of your terminal, for example, and won't work in a script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to decode it in python2:

```
"I❤U".decode('utf-8')
```

Output: `u'I\u2764U'`

then `len("I❤U".decode('utf-8'))`, it will be `3`

Comment: Note that this assumes that the terminal is configured with a UTF-8 locale.

Answer (score -1):

In my env, I tried your code. But my result of len("I❤U") is 3.

```
>>> len("I❤U")
3
>>>
```

Comment: Not in Python 2 it won't. For UTF-8 encoded data, you'd get 5. Try `"I❤U".encode('utf8')` in Python 3. OR `b'I\xe2\x9d\xa4U'`, which is what the OP actually has.